# Handling JSON POST request in PHP

Tags: php, android, json, post, request

I am currently developing Android application, which will uses web services. I used PHP for backend. I am currently trying authentication via JSON to PHP. But I am stuck at some point, hope u guys will help.

I successfully write code to create JSON data in android also db connections in php using mysql, but i am confusing about how to handle JSON data. I am using POST request for sending JSON data.

I like to ask how i handle JSON data in PHP. More specific, I like to know how to grab POST request in PHP which contain JSON data??

Thanks in advance.
Thanking you.

EDIT:
I am using following code for sending POST request in android

```
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(address);
            json.put("username", username);
        json.put("password", pwd);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("json"+json.toString());
        Log.i(DEB_TAG, "The JSON Request is:"+json.toString());
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,          "application/json"));
        post.setEntity(se);
        Log.i(DEB_TAG, "The post request is "+post.toString());
        response = client.execute(post);

        if(response != null){
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            Log.i(DEB_TAG, "The result is"+in.toString());
            }
```

and using following code for parsing JSON request in php:

```
 $string = $_POST['josnHeader'];
 $obj = json_decode($string);
 $username = $obj->{'username'};
 $password = $obj->{'password'};
```

Is it correct or I am doing any wrong implementation??

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look in your $_POST array in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = $_POST["var_name"];
$array = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = $_REQUEST["your_param"];
$dtoObject = json_decode(stripslashes($json),true);
```